How to output the sum of each element and its preceding elements?
This question is an extend of the question How to sum all the elements in a group in specific row with the package listofitems?

I'd like to output the sum of each element and its preceding elements in the array of listofitems package automatically.
The MWE is the following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\foo{
    foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
    3,1,4,1,5
}

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

How can I output the sum of each element and its preceding elements? Such as: 3,4,8,9,14 (Correspond to 3,3+1,3+1+4,3+1+4+1,3+1+4+1+5).

\end{document}

What's more, I'd like to keep using the listofitems package, not to replace this package with expl3 program, but someone can just using expl3 to output the summations.

do you want to specify the row? or do you want the function to automatically output the sums for every row? if the latter, what do you want to happen if (1) none of the elements in the row are integers, (2) some but not all are integers, (3) some or all are numbers but not integers?

@cfr Just specify the row is okay. Output the sums of the second line in the MWE.

With listofitems? I don't know why. Anyway,
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\foo{
    foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
    3,1,4,1,5
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__meiu_sums_in_clist
\clist_new:N \l__meiu_sums_out_clist
\clist_new:N \l__meiu_sums_tmp_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\partialsums}{mmo}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = row, #3 = macro name for storing
  \clist_set:Ne \l__meiu_sums_in_clist { #1[#2] }
  \clist_clear:N \l__meiu_sums_out_clist
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:N \l__meiu_sums_in_clist }
   {% ##1 is the highest term
    \clist_clear:N \l__meiu_sums_tmp_clist
    \int_step_inline:nn { ##1 }
     {% populate the tmp clist
      \clist_put_right:Ne \l__meiu_sums_tmp_clist { \clist_item:Nn \l__meiu_sums_in_clist {####1} }
     }
    \clist_put_right:Ne \l__meiu_sums_out_clist
     {% do the partial sum
      \int_eval:n { \clist_use:Nn \l__meiu_sums_tmp_clist { + } }
     }
   }
  \IfNoValueTF {#3}
   {% no optional argument, deliver the result
    \clist_use:Nn \l__meiu_sums_out_clist {,~}
   }
   {% optional argument, store
    \cs_if_exist:NTF { #3 }
     {
      \ERROR
     }
     {
      \tl_set:Ne #3 { \clist_use:Nn \l__meiu_sums_out_clist {,} }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there 
are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

The partial sums of row two are \partialsums{\foo}{2}

Store:\partialsums{\foo}{2}[\baz]
\texttt{\meaning\baz}

\end{document}


In order to get single partial sums, you can define
\NewDocumentCommand{\partialsum}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = row, #3 = last index
  \clist_set:Ne \l__meiu_sums_in_clist { #1[#2] }
  \clist_clear:N \l__meiu_sums_out_clist
  \int_step_inline:nn {#3}
   {% populate the shortened clist
    \clist_put_right:Ne \l__meiu_sums_out_clist { \clist_item:Nn \l__meiu_sums_in_clist {##1} }
   }
  \int_eval:n { \clist_use:Nn \l__meiu_sums_out_clist {+} }
 }

If you add this and append
\partialsum{\foo}{2}{1},
\partialsum{\foo}{2}{2},
\partialsum{\foo}{2}{3},
\partialsum{\foo}{2}{4},
\partialsum{\foo}{2}{5}.

before `\end{document}, you'll get


Elegant! What's more, could you output the partial sums one by one? Such as \partialsums{\foo}{2,1},\partialsums{\foo}{2,2},\partialsums{\foo}{2,3},\partialsums{\foo}{2,4},\partialsums{\foo}{2,5} 3,4,8,9,14.

@Meiu Added. I'm not sure about your target, but you're the judge.

The output is correct. But, I can only use the outputs in tikz for node: I can \tikz{\foreach \a in {1,...,5}   {     \node at (\a,0) {\partialsum{\foo}{2}{\a}};   }}, but I could not \tikz{\foreach \a in {1,...,5}   {     \draw (\partialsum{\foo}{2}{\a}, 0) --++ (1,1);   }}, I don't know what causes it could not be used in coordinate calculation.

@Skyrmion No, \partialsum is not expandable. You can add an optional argument to store the result like it's done for \partialsums.
